# Can't declare global variable in C++ even after defining the class?

Tags: c++, eclipse, global-variables

I'm having a problem declaring a global variable just after I declare a datatype in c++. So I declare the class (note, this is within another .cpp file) and then try to declare the variable `tree` afterwards. The `BST *tree = new BST();` gives me a undefined reference error but if I define it in my main it's fine. The problem is that I need to use it before I get into my main. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Node { 

public:

    INT64 volatile key;
    Node* volatile left;
    Node* volatile right;

    Node() {key = 0; right = left = NULL;} //default
};

class BST{

public:

    Node* volatile root;

    BST();
    int contains(INT64 key);
    int add(Node *nn);
    Node* remove(INT64 key);
};

int BST::add(Node *n){
    Node *volatile *pp = &root;
    Node *p = root;
    while(p){
        if(n->key > p->key){
            pp = &p->left;
        } else if (n->key > p->key){
            pp = &p->right;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
        p = *pp;
    }
    *pp = n;
    return 1;
}

Node* BST::remove(INT64 key){
    Node *volatile *pp = &root;
    Node *p = root;
    while(p){
        if(key < p->key){
            pp = &p->left;
        } else if(key > p->key){
            pp = &p->right;
        } else{
            break;
        }
        p = *pp;
    }

    if(p == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    if(p->left == NULL && p->right == NULL){
        *pp = NULL;
    } else if(p->left == NULL){
        *pp = p->right;
    } else if(p->right == NULL){
        *pp = p->left;
    } else{
        Node *r = p->right;
        Node *volatile *ppr = &p->right;
        while(r->left){
            ppr = &r->left;
            r = r->left;
        }
        p->key = r->key;
        p = r;
        *ppr = r->right;
    }
    return p;
}

BST *tree = new BST();
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please use only the relevant language tag.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the "undefined reference error" is a linker error, which indicates that the implementation of a declared method is missing. In this case, constructor `BST()` is declared, but not implemented. Just to give it a try, if you enter `BST() {}` instead of `BST();`, it should work.

So this is actually not a problem of "having a global variable declared at a wrong place"; If you declare a global variable of the form `BST *tree = new BST()`, the compiler will check if `BST` declares a corresponding constructor (explicitly or implicitly); and such a constructor is declared explicitly, so the compiler will not raise any error. However, as the constructor `BST()` now is referred to in the code, the linker will have to bind an implementation to the declared constructor `BST()`, and it will raise an error if it does not find one.

Comment: No need to have the `;` in `BST() {};`, `BST() {}` is sufficient.